# Issue using naming conventions and prefixes in automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I set up a simple console application, and I'm trying to convert:

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

To:

```
public class user_dto
{
    public string ud_first_name { get; set; }
    public string ud_lastname { get; set; }
}
```

and then convert them **back**. Here's my attempt:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static void RegisterMappings()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.RecognizeDestinationPrefixes(new []{"ud_"});
            cfg.RecognizePrefixes(new[] { "ud_" });
            cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
            cfg.SourceMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();

            cfg.CreateMap<User, user_dto>().ReverseMap();
        });
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMappings();

    var newUser = new User
    {
        FirstName = "John",
        LastName = "Doe"
    };

    var newUser2 = new user_dto
    {
        ud_first_name = "Marry",
        ud_lastname = "Jane"
    };

    var newUserDTO = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<user_dto>(newUser);

    Console.Write(newUserDTO.ud_first_name + " " + newUserDTO.ud_lastname);

    var newUserViewModel = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<User>(newUser2);

    Console.Write(newUserViewModel.FirstName + " " + newUserViewModel.LastName);
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

This works fine for converting the last name, but not the first name. Per [the docs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration) the naming convention being setup as I have it should convert `first_name` -> `FirstName`, but it silently fails and only the `lastname` is converted.

Interestingly enough, if I remove the prefix lines in the config and also remove the leading `ud_` from the `user_dto` and run the application, John Doe's whole name is converted, but only Marry's last name is converted. Are you not able to remove prefixis and use the naming conventions to convert with automapper? Is there supposed to be a different/better way to achieve what I'm trying?

Comment: is it because you have inconsistent underscores, e.g. `first_name` and `lastname`. shouldn't it be `firstname` and `lastname` or `first_name` and `last_name`

Comment: @DaveBecker I don't think so, as it converts as expected without the prefix in place. The missing underscore in `lastname` is intentional. basically i need the `ud_`, removed, and i need to map lower case with/without underscores to pascal casing.

Comment: Just had a nightmare installing AutoMapper!! Mer! anyway.... I changed the properties to `ud_firstname` and `ud_lastname` and it worked a treat in version `4.2.1`

Comment: @DaveBecker Is there no way to convert with the underscores? My goal is to convert `first_name` to `FirstName` **and** `lastname` to `LastName` and also remove the `ud_` prefix. From what I understand of the docs, it should work as I have it, but there seems to be some issue (a bug maybe?) with the prefixes and the naming conventions working together.

Comment: TBH I do not know. But this has got me now!! I think you may be able to explicitly map, I'm just playing around with it now....

Comment: @DaveBecker Yeah it's more of a curious oddity for me at this point than a frustration, just not sure if I am misunderstanding the documentation or if I understand it and it's not working as intended. May make a post on the github repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works as expected:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateProfile("UserViewModelToDto", prf =>
        {
            prf.RecognizeDestinationPrefixes(new[] { "ud" });
            prf.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
            prf.CreateMap<User, user_dto>();
        });

        cfg.CreateProfile("UserDtoToViewModel", prf =>
        {
            prf.RecognizePrefixes(new[] { "ud_" });
            prf.SourceMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
            prf.CreateMap<user_dto, User>();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you are able to change the names of properties in the dto but if you can it seems to work fine in version 4.2.1 or AutoMapper if you make consistent the use of underscores.

```
public class user_dto
{
    public string ud_firstname { get; set; }
    public string ud_lastname { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
John DoeMary Jane
```

I would guess that AutoMapper is getting confused with the number of underscores, which is why it partially worked when you removed the `ud_` part

UPDATE:

This feels wrong but it does work, so maybe it is a workaround in this situation. Add the following lines to the config to allow for custom mapping after the auto mapping has been done.

```
cfg.CreateMap<User, user_dto>().ReverseMap().AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.FirstName = src.ud_first_name);
cfg.CreateMap<user_dto, User>().ReverseMap().AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.ud_first_name = src.FirstName);
```

Full Config Class:

```
public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static void RegisterMappings()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.RecognizeDestinationPrefixes(new []{"ud_"});
            cfg.RecognizePrefixes(new[] { "ud_" });
            cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
            cfg.SourceMemberNamingConvention = new PascalCaseNamingConvention();
            cfg.CreateMap<User, user_dto>().ReverseMap().AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.FirstName = src.ud_first_name);
            cfg.CreateMap<user_dto, User>().ReverseMap().AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.ud_first_name = src.FirstName);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You make an interesting point about the underscore in the `ud`. If I change property names to `udfirst_name` and `udlastname`, then make the change to the prefix removal in the config `cfg.RecognizePrefixes(new[] { "ud" });` it seems to work. This isn't the functionality I desire, however. My property names in the production app i plan to use this test case in have the `ud_`

Comment: yeah sorry, it took a while for the penny to drop as to what you are trying to achieve. And I agree, something doesn't look quite right here.

Comment: I've added an update that may help. But I think it is worth pursuing on git hub because although it works, you are technically manually mapping.

Comment: Yep that route works, it's what i am currently doing in production, I made the console application to test a smaller sample size and see if it can be simplified. [put an issue in however](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2079)